# Shisha Vetish'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred ninety-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Maharal and many other Seforim the number 7 is for Teva (natural) and the number 8 is for L'Maala Min HaTeva (supernatural). 8 days x 24 hours = 196 hours.

One of the supernatural miracles that was done for Bnei Yisroel was the splitting of the red sea. Hence the Gematria of ים סוף = 196

Answer (score 1):

[Reportedly](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22196+children%22+britain+germany), the first [Kindertransport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindertransport) contained 196 children.